# Javascript variable in razor ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

```
var boxIdValue = 233;
var result = title + '<br/>@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Show", "Boxes", new{boxId=233}, null)';
```

When I hardcode `boxId` then it works. But when I write:

```
var result = title + '<br/>@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Show", "Boxes", new{boxId=boxIdValue}, null)';
```

It doesn't. Is it possible to mix javascript var and razor in this way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have a look at [this related Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745139/building-relative-urls-for-an-mvc-app-with-javascript/) question.

The reason why this is a challenge is that the Razor method executes on the web server at render time while the javascript executes on the client browser at runtime.

I would solve this by doing something like

```
var boxIdValue = 233;
var link = '@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Show", "Boxes", new{boxId=-1}, null)'
link = link.replace('-1', boxIdValue);
var result = title + '<br />' + link;
```

Comment: This only works if you dont have a second parameter. Something  like new{boxId=-1,page=1} will fail.The separator & will be html encoded as &amp; and page parameter will not be available on the cation. For it to work you need to use @Html.Raw(Html.ActionLink...

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. My head was in the clouds and your common sense reply helped me see things clearly and continue with my day with a smile on my face!