# pass variable as parameter to Url.Action in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am passing parameters to @Url.Action like this:

```
function showHistory()
{

myId= $("#id").val();
    //alert(myId);
    actionDialog.load("@Url.Action("ActionHistoryAjax", new {id = myId, sort = "abc"})", function   () {
        actionDialog.dialog('open');
    });
}
```

But gives error "the name myId does not exist in the current context".

How i can pass the variable?

I solved this, this is the solution:

```
function showHistory()
{

myId= $("#id").val();
//alert(myId);
actionDialog.load("@Url.Action("ActionHistoryAjax", new {id = "_Id", sort = "abc"})".replace("_Id", DeviceID), function   ()     {
 actionDialog.dialog('open');
});
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751109/javascript-variable-in-razor-actionlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751109/javascript-variable-in-razor-actionlink)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it by using this:

```
function showHistory()
{
    myId= $("#id").val();
    actionDialog.load("@Url.Action("ActionHistoryAjax", new {id = "_Id", sort = "abc"})".replace("_Id", DeviceID), function   ()     {
        actionDialog.dialog('open');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing server-side and client-side code here. You can't pass a Javascript variable into the Url.Action method like that.

You would need to do something like:

```
function showHistory()
{
    myId= $("#id").val();
    actionDialog.load("@Url.Action("ActionHistoryAjax", new { sort = "abc"})" + 
                      "&id=" + encodeURIComponent(myId), function   () {
        actionDialog.dialog('open');
    });
}
```

Or else load that ID from the server model.

Answer (score -1):

```
old one
function showHistory()
{

  myId= $("#id").val();
  //alert(myId);
  actionDialog.load("@Url.Action("ActionHistoryAjax", new {id = myId, sort = "abc"})", 
  function   () {
    actionDialog.dialog('open');
  });
}
```

New one

```
function showHistory()
{

 myId= $("#id").val();
 //alert(myId);
    actionDialog.load("@Url.Action("ActionHistoryAjax", new {id = "+ myId +", 
     sort =    "abc"})", function   () {
     actionDialog.dialog('open');
 });
}
```

Comment: That won't work. That would attempt to assign the string value "+ myId +" to id

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I literally got the text "myId" as the value for id.