# javascript parameter doesnt exist in the current context

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

why doesnt this work? how can i declare these? considering topicid will be an int and topicname will be a string.

```
function changetotopicdetail(topicid, topicname) {
    $('#loadingAjaxs').show();
    $('#flubestext').hide();
    $('#contentwrap').load('@Url.Action("Detail", "Topics", new { @id = topicid,  @namespace = topicname, @Forum = "all", @page = 0})', function () { 
    $('#loadingAjaxs').hide();
   $('#flubestext').show(); 
   window.history.pushState(null, 'title', '/topics');
   })
}
```

thanks

Comment: see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751109/javascript-variable-in-razor-actionlink

Comment: i dont see how that has any relevence to my question?

Comment: @alxndr posted a question that is totally relative to yours... is the same mistake you're doing on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to @alxndr tip, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9751109/1267304) has the same mistake and it is solved with a code like that:

```
function changetotopicdetail(topicid, topicname) {
    $('#loadingAjaxs').show(); 
    $('#flubestext').hide();

    var link = '@Url.Action("Detail", "Topics", new { @id = -1,  @namespace = -2, @Forum = "all", @page = 0})';

    link = link.replace("-1", topicid);
    link = link.replace("-2", topicname);

    $('#contentwrap').load(link, function () { 
        $('#loadingAjaxs').hide();
        $('#flubestext').show(); 
        window.history.pushState(null, 'title', '/topics'); 
    });
}
```

You mistake is that you're trying to access two JavaScript variables(`topicid` and `topicname`) in the Razor - view - context. Razor can't access it, so those two variables are unknown for it. What the code is doing is to print the `@Url.Action` result on a JavaScript variable and then, in JavaScript (where you can access those parameters) replace that link *joker* chars `-1` and `-2` with the parameters. So you got the link the way you need it. Hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: @user1311546 I'm glad to hear it!!