# How to pass javascript variable into @Model function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently trying to only show certain entries of a list passed in from my controller method depending on which page the user chooses from the pagination bar, which looks like this

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a>
        </li>
        @for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
        {
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="showResults(@i)">@i</a>
            </li>
        }
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h4>
        Retrieved @Model.Count() results - currently showing 10 per page
    </h4>
</nav>
```

For some context, `numberOfPages` is a razor variable defined as `Model.Count()/10 + 1`. Right now I'm just trying to get the right elements from the passed-in list. However in my showResults method, I'm unable to use javascript variables in functions involving `@Model`.

```
<script>
    function showResults(page) {
        //no need to reload the current page
        if (page == @currentPage){
            return;
        }
        page = page - 1; //e.g. if user wants to go to page 1, then results gathered would be from 0 to 9
        var items = @Model.Skip(page * 10).Take(10);
    }
</script>
```

On the line, `var items = @Model.Skip(page * 10).Take(10);`, I get an error that says

> The name 'page' does not exist in the current context

One thing I tried was from [Javascript variable in razor ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751109/javascript-variable-in-razor-actionlink?noredirect=1&lq=1), but the answer here involving `replace` would give me an "Uncaught Syntax" error. I would like any way to filter a list using a javascript variable, if possible.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what code runs on the client and what runs on the server. `showResults` must make an ajax call or a redirect to your view passing the new page number.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible - you can't mix javascript into razor functions since javascript is client side and razor is compiled before the page is served, hence the error that you received.

Answer (score 0):

Do the skip take operation to a razor variable. You cannot do a server side calculation with a client side parameter.

If your Model contains all data, why do you need to filter out the data using razor? Assign the data to a JavaScript variable and do your skip take on your show result method.

If you want to load data dynamically than do an Ajax call for that page and fill your model with that data only. Afterwards do the second paragraph again :)

Comment: Suppose I had the whole list inside the view, would I be able to filter it out without ajax? The reason I'm filtering the data is because I would like to implement pagination in a single page. So if the user wants to see results 10-19, the user can go to page 2.