# MVC jquery get not working for non hardcoded get

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app which has a home controller with the method GetResult in it:

```
public int GetResult()
        {
            return 3;
        }
```

I call it in a javascript file using:

```
$.post('/Home/GetResult', null, function (data) {

        alert(data);

    });
```

and it works fine.

However I tried to use a none hardcorded way of calling it

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetResult", "Home")', null, function (data) {

        alert(data);

    });
```

It's not working I'm getting a 500 errir.

It's trying to get to the URL:

```
http://localhost:xx/Home/@Url.Action(%22GetResult%22,%20%%22Home%22)
```

Well this is obviously isn't right.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is the get call inside a razor view or external javascript ?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745139/building-relative-urls-for-an-mvc-app-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Razor syntax inside a JavaScript file. Razor is a server-side scripting construct that needs to be parsed by ASP.Net to function.

You have two options:

**Option One:**

Move the script into the `.cshtml` view file.

**Option Two:**

Create a JavaScript function that accepts the url as a param and call it from the view:

```
function foo(posturl){
    $.post(url, null, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}

/* View */
foo('@Url.Action("GetResult", "Home")');
```

Answer (score 0):

It works on Razor views only.If you want to access it on a exteranl javascript file, You may get the Path name using the HTML Helper method  in a razor view and Keep that in a Global java script variable and access that in the external javascript file

in your View,

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  var globalGetResultPath='@Url.ACtion("GetResult","Home)';
</script>
```

And in the external script now you can call like

```
$.get(globalGetResultPath, function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```