# Passing date parameters to @url.action via ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax, url.action

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 app, I'm using the following JAX code taken from this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745139/building-relative-urls-for-an-mvc-app-with-javascript/9745226#9745226) to pass Date parameters to a controller but I am getting the following http 404 error: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Requested URL /myWebApp/myController/myAction/01/01/2014/12/31/2014"

Here the input controls txtFrom and txtTo have the values 01/01/2014 and 12/31/2014 respectively. the issue is that MVC is probably interpreting each date as three different parameters. How can we fix it. I tried replacing $('#txtFrom').val() with $('#txtFrom').val().replace("///g", "_") but it does not work.

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("myAction")/' + $('#txtFrom').val() + '/' + $('#txtTo').val();
```

**Action method**:

```
public ActionResult myAction(string startDate, string endDate)
{
 //simple code here to use the input parameters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either format the date string with Razor

```
@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(date)
```

with javascript

```
encodeURIComponent(date)
```

or pass the date as ticks (milliseconds since Epoch) instead of the human-readable format.

**Edit:**

After experimenting with this and a bit of research it seems the slash and `%2f` encoding causes all kinds of problems. Stick to the millisecond representation for a date and not worry about passing the slash.

Comment: per your advice I tried @HttpUtility.UrlEncode(date) and through Chrome Developer tool, I noticed that the URL formation is correctly displayed as: "/myWebApp/myController/myAction/01%2F01%2F2014/12%2F31%2F2014". But I am still getting the same error: resource not found Requested URL /myWebApp/myController/myAction/01/01/2014/12/31/2014"

Comment: Try it as `/myAction?startDate=x&endDate=x`. If that works then it might be an issue with your routing rules. Ticks might be the safest option since that would not contain any special characters.

Comment: `/myAction?startDate=x&endDate=x` worked. But then what could be an issue with the routing rules that causes `/myAction/startDate/endDate` not to work?

Comment: The `%2f` is translated back to slash before the routing is performed. There are various ways people get around this issue such as substituting the `/` for a different character. You can do this within the IIS settings but that all seems like more work than it's worth when you could just pass the ticks as `/myAction/xxx/xxx`. Alternatively, you can format date as `mmddyyyy` and that would be more readable than ticks. Also note that `mm/dd/yyyy` can easily be mistaken for `dd/mm/yyyy` and the millisecond representation avoids this case.

Answer (score 0):

**window.location.href** is not ajax. Its your browser making a HTTP get request to the url. In your case, its not a complete url, but a partial; thus the error. You may try the following for start. Substitute the hardcoded values for dates with your inputs

```
$.getJSON({‘@Url.Action("myAction")’ + '/', { startDate: ‘1/1/2001’, endData: ‘1/2/2002’ }});
```

If you want to process any return value; refer to jquery documentation on $.getJSON (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)